# How can i solve this overloading error in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, overloading

I am new to angular and was building a login page while connecting it with the login api i built
in the login component i am facing this issue

```
   No overload matches this call.
    Overload 1 of 2, '(observerOrNext?: Partial<Observer<Object>> | ((value: Object) => void) |                  undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(res: boolean) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<Observer<Object>> | ((value: Object) => void) | undefined'.
  Type '(res: boolean) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: Object) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
      Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Overload 2 of 2, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(res: boolean) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2769)
(parameter) res: boolean

This is my login.component.ts class

```
       import { Component, OnInit, resolveForwardRef } from '@angular/core';
       import { UserserviceService } from '../userservice.service';
       import { Router } from '@angular/router';

     @Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
   getData: boolean = false;
   model: any = {};


   constructor(
   private router: Router, private userservice: UserserviceService

  ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
   }

   loginUser() {


var user = this.model.username;
var password = this.model.password;

 
this.userservice.getUserData(user, password).subscribe((res: boolean) => {
    this.getData = res;
    

    if (this.getData == true) {
     
     this.router.navigate(["/home"])
    } else {
     alert("Invalid users")
    }
  });
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `getUserData` method from `UserserviceService` in the question?

Comment: getUserData(username: string,password: string){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user/'+username+'/'+password);

  }

Comment: By default, `HttpClient.get()` returns an `Observable<Object>`. Try change to `this.http.get<boolean>(...)` to return `Observable<boolean>`. Assume that the response returned is a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because the response of getUserData api might not be of boolean format. So you have to remove type boolean from (res:boolean) while subscribing and you have to make an interface of type response data. Or you can keep it as **any** instead of boolean.

and in the next line while comparing  you cannot compare in if condition like this (this.getData == true), because getData may have different value (i.e, might not be a boolean value). so either you have to compare any key inside that getData object to confirm and navigate to login, or you can just do it as if(this.getData){}

Hope this solves your issue.
keep coding :-)